# Line with Infinite slope and parabola

Tags: functions, tangent-line, secant

Given a line with a slope of infinite (g(x)=infinite*x) and a parabola (f(x)=x^2)... are they a secant or a tangent?

Since the g(x) is going straight up they will only cross once at (0|0), they should count as a tangent but it it is still crossing it which would make it a secant?
Is there any way of calculating this?

Comment: tangent is a straight line or plane that touches a curve or curved surface at a point, but if extended does not cross it at that point. (Google dictionary).

Comment: @Vasya : Not quite correct. A tangent can cross the curve at infinitely many points in every neighborhood of the point of tangency (I think something like $y=x^2\sin\tfrac1x$ shows this).

Comment: @MPW: That's why it says "at that point"

Comment: @Vasya : Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood. I thought you meant the extension couldn't cross away from the point of tangency. So you are basically saying it touches but does not cross at the point of tangency? That's also incorrect. Consider $y=x^3$ at the origin. The tangent can cross a curve at a saddle point.

Comment: @MPW: It's just a definition that came up in Google and it looked fine to me. I haven't really thought about it that deeply. What definition would you give?

Comment: @Vasya : I suppose it's pretty difficult to describe in layman's terms very precisely without using mathematics. I could accept your original definition to get the gist across, but then would refine it. In plain English, what I said at the end of my answer is similar in meaning. Technically, the tangent is the "best local linear approximation" to the curve. But that just hides the mathematics in technical words.

Comment: @MPW: I agree that we accept some definitions as given but it's not easy sometimes to put the definition in layman's terms. Your example of $f(x)=x^3$ made me think how would I explain that tangent to a line is a line itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical lines have equations of the form $x=c$, not the usual slope-intercept form.

I presume you mean the line $x=0$ (the vertical line through the origin). This is *not* a tangent line for the curve $y=x^2$ at $(0,0)$. The tangent line at that point is actually *horizontal*, so it is $y=0x+0$, or just $y=0$.

So your vertical line is secant, not tangent.

Tangents "graze" the curve; they represent the straight line that best matches the "direction" of the curve at a given point.